# XTerm*metaSendsEscape broken when Alt_R is mod4

Tags: x11, xterm, xmodmap

I can't get `xterm` to behave correctly re: the `metaSendsEscape` setting.

When I have this as my `Xmodmap`, the setting doesn't work (i.e., `xterm` ignores the Alt keys even when `metaSendsEscape` is enabled):

```
clear mod4
clear mod1
add mod4 = Alt_R
add mod1 = Alt_L
```

However, when I do this, it works:

```
clear mod4
clear mod1
add mod1 = Alt_R
add mod1 = Alt_L
```

But, this isn't what I want; I *really* want my right Alt key to be mod4. Anyone know a workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The work-around is to add some unused key to `Alt_R`. This works:

```
clear mod4
clear mod1

! Make right alt key the super key.
keycode 108 = Super_R

! Assume Line feed key unused.
keycode 109 = Alt_R

add mod1 = Alt_L
add mod1 = Alt_R
add mod4 = Super_R
```